# Does Mongo indexes have smaller size if I have indexes with common prefixes

Tags: mongodb

I have two indexes

```
{a:1,b:1,c:1} and {a:1,b:1,d:1}
```

Will hashes `a` and `a+b` will be stored twice or is MongoDB "smart" enough to make only one tree?

Comment: Don't know why people are voting to close, this question looks clear to me

Comment: I think it's because extremely basic database theory. In my opinion and based on how a B-Tree is built, it should be smart enough to store it once.